# Can't pass data from children to parent component with emit

Tags: vue.js

I need to pass data from children to parent component. Code is very simple, but I can't understand what and where I am missing.

```
export default {
  name: 'TableOfContent',
  props: ['itemGUID'], // is it nessosary? 
  methods: {
      itemClick(itemGUID)
      {
        console.log(itemGUID);
        this.$emit('newchapter', itemGUID) // passing GUID to parent
      }
  }
}
```

Parent template:

```
<template>
    <div class="Book" v-on:newchapter="foo(itemGUID)">
        {{msg}}
    </div>
</template>


<script>
import toc from './TableOfContent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'mybook',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'my main book'
    }
  },
  methods:
  {
      foo(itemGUID)
      {
          console.log("GUID is: ", itemGUID);
      }
  },

   components: {toc}

}
</script>
```

This code do not work :(

Comment: are you getting undefined?

Comment: Where are you using `TableOfContent ` in the template, can you create a fiddle? [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tiagomatosweb/vqtnpyzw/) is one example of sending argument in emit event.

Comment: @Saurabh it's look like `foo()` is no calling. I do not getting nothing to console.

I will try to do it.

Comment: It should be `this.$emit('newchapter', this.itemGUID)` into the tableofcontent component.

Comment: @Belmin with `.this` I am getting undefined in `itemClick` method.

Comment: Does the itemGUID prop contains any value ? maybe it's by default undefined

Comment: `console.log` print it's value, so it's ok

Answer (score 1):

Just do following in template:

```
<template>
    <div class="Book" v-on:newchapter="foo">
        {{msg}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: same effect :( sorry that I did not jsfiddle, it's a litle bit hard for me. 
The console.log of children component works fine. I see values on console. But in parent component `foo` seems not triggered, because I do not see on console (data not passing?)

Comment: @user1432751 Where are you using TableOfContent in the template,

Comment: Nowhere. Should I use it? If I do:
```
    <toc>
        <div class="Book" v-on:newchapter='foo'>
            {{msg}}
        </div>
    </toc>
```

I am getting full copy of Table Of Content. But I need only pass ID  from TOC component

Comment: @user1432751 Than only you will be able to use the component, right?

Comment: What do you mean? I need just pass the ID to other component. My app would swith content when user will click on TOC element.

Comment: @user1432751 How are you passing Id?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137556/discussion-between-user1432751-and-saurabh).